# Creating a User control panel for multiple user_types in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am developing a job portal website as part of a project for university and not exactly sure how to approach this problem, I  am using [Devise](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPgZ3G4YLNAhXKAcAKHcBBCrIQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fplataformatec%2Fdevise&usg=AFQjCNEeA0g0Bkjn8rvAQLjC7WZ48OBE-Q&bvm=bv.123325700,d.ZGg) for my authentication system allowing users to sign, The system will have many user_types (job_seeker, company).

At the moment I am using “[Rails_admin](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiN8Im_4YLNAhXMLsAKHX7UA6EQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fsferik%2Frails_admin&usg=AFQjCNHq0kIg1ZsPBGCWwVsHDkhjebtisQ&bvm=bv.123325700,d.ZGg)” for the admin interface, but I am looking to create an interface where a company can manage their jobs, applications, etc, and for job_seekers to view their previous job applications, and job status etc.

My plan was to develop it so in the controller it checked the user_type and then redirected it to a control panel, which would hopefully allow all users go sign in using one login page, but my question is, how do I go about developing a “job_seeker” and “Company” control panels where they can manage their details.

I am looking for information on how to approach this problem, or the best method to achieve a solution.

Comment: Well I guess you can create different controllers for each type of users. Before any action, checking if there is any user logged in and if the type of user correspond well to the current controller. If some controllers have the same name, you can create namespaces. A namespace is just a subfolder of controllers. (there are probably a lot of other techniques but my knowledge is yet limited)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a gem that allow you or simplified role user management  like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)?

A good approach is as Maxence said, have a namespace for every role and a dashboard controller to show what you need. This will help you to keep things spited and will be more easy to maintenance. You can check it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) how use namespaces. You can do it as well with a resource but I dont like it.

Other thing that you can do is having a single dashboard controller and redirect depending of the user role.